# Where can I get a list of .deb packages on the alternate CD?

Tags: installation, deb, alternate

I'd like to install Ubuntu in my computer. I learned that if I install an alternate version, I can choose the .deb packages I need. But when I log in the system, I always face the problem that there are some packages I should have installed which I have not.

I tried a desktop version, and it ran well. So it must be that I made some mistakes when installed it.

So where can I get a list of .deb packages, and what are these .debs used for?

Comment: Welcome Laurie Li , you mentioned about some packages you wanted to install but had not , can you please specify which ones you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**.deb** packages are basically the installable Applications packages ( similar to Windows **.exe** ) packed by and for **Ubuntu**.

The **Ubuntu Alternate Cd version** avails advanced mode of installation suited for experienced and professional users to control every part of Installation.

For viewing the **.deb** packages and the application related to them , you can visit [Packages.Ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/).

For installing through Alternate CD , you can view this [Illustrated guide](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p2.html)

For installing other packages that you thought was missing , you can search for them in **Ubuntu software center** available in the **Dash** menu or by pressing `super+A` keys , or through [Ubuntu Applications Web page](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/).

Answer (score 0):

.deb files are debian package files. These are often used to install programs. Alternate versions (of Ubuntu) are just Ubuntu with a different list of .debs. Ubuntu Software Center installs these .deb files. And welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Also, see [Ubuntu minimal and must have packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24638/ubuntu-minimal-and-must-have-packages) and search Ask Ubuntu for "minimal CD".